# SLA is not saving in database. Also not trigger any mail in airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have successfully setup smtp server. also working fine in case of job failed.
But I tried to set SLA miss as per the below link.

> https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/airflow-service-level-agreement-sla-2f3c91cd84cc

```
mid = BashOperator(
task_id='mid',
sla=timedelta(seconds=5),
bash_command='sleep 10',
retries=0,
dag=dag,
)
```

There is no event saving . Also i have checked through as below

```
Browse->SLA misses
```

I have tried more. Unable to catch the issue.

the dag is defined as :

```
args = {
  'owner': 'airflow',
  'start_date': datetime(2020, 11, 18),
  'catchup':False,
  'retries': 0,
  'provide_context': True,
  'email' : "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com",
  'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(n=0, minute=1),
  'priority_weight': 1,
  'email_on_failure' : True,
   'default_args':{
        'on_failure_callback': on_failure_callback,
    }
}
d = datetime(2020, 10, 30)



dag = DAG('MyApplication', start_date = d,on_failure_callback=on_failure_callback, schedule_interval = '@daily', default_args = args)
```

Comment: How is the DAG defined? And the default args?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis code edit for the DAG.

Comment: Hmm, this looks all good on a first look. Did you try to increase the sleep to a few minutes? Maybe the scheduler is not fast enough to regisger the sla miss.

Comment: Ah! I see the problem - see the answer.

Comment: @PhilippJohannis , sla is not saving in database.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in the arguments, more specifically `'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(n=0, minute=1)`, this means that start_date gets newly interpreted every time the scheduler parses the DAG file. You should specify a "static" start date like `datetime(2020,11,18)`.

See also [Airflow FAQ](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date):

> We recommend against using dynamic values as start_date, especially datetime.now() as it can be quite confusing. The task is triggered once the period closes, and in theory an @hourly DAG would never get to an hour after now as now() moves along.

Also specifying default_args inside of args seems weird to me.

Comment: default_args is used here for some custom event can be trigger , here on failure i am calling custom method

Comment: SLA is not saving is sla_miss table

Comment: Did you set a fixed start_date?

Comment: yes i have fixed the date,but date has no issue, if i increase the sleep time its sending the messages, but event is not saved in database

Comment: but nesting default_args into args seems wrong. it should be directly in `args` as you specify default_args = args in your DAG and this means that Airflow will pass all args to each task. on_failure_callback should be therefore similar to 'email_on_failure' on the same level.

Comment: Also `catchup` is a DAG property, not a task property, therefore it will not work putting these into `args`, it needs to be passed to `DAG()` - see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-run.html#catchup

Comment: But setting the start date dynamically has an impact on the SLA because it's used to calculate the SLA miss

Comment: Maybe also give a DAG a new name when retrying. Changing start dates, schedules on an existing DAG can cause problems.

Comment: sla is not triggered in case of manual triggered. If the job is scheduled then sla is working fine.

Comment: That makes sense, as I said, the SLA calculation is based on start_date + interval. A manual triggered job doesn't fit into the interval.